# Failed media import

Tags: media, import, permissions, uploads

I sat up MAMP on my mac and installed wordpress 3.1. Then, I exported my wordpress.com ina tried to import to my local wordpress.... I ticked import media option and I was hoping that I will get all my posta and attachments copied across but I got only posts imported properly... For each and every attachment at wordpress.com I got error saying media import failed!!

Am I doing something wrong? Please help I have thousands of PDF/jpg attachments which I want imported...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem... my source blog was private i.e. required password... I made it public for couple of minutes, and importer plugin did it's job properly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that your uploads folder (usually `wp-content/uploads`) was writable by your local apache server?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: In Finder, right-click (CTRL-click) on the folder, and choose "Get Info". In the "Sharing and Permissions" section, set the "everyone" entry to "Read & Write". That should do the trick.

Comment: just did that.. still same problem "Failed to import Media"!

Comment: No good... Amy other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had any other thoughts, and don't have time at the moment to look at the import code for ideas. :-/