# Failed Media Import (importing from LIVE to local)

Tags: import

When I try to import some content to my local site so I can work on the theme w/ relevant data, my import hangs forever.... and if it finishes then the media/images fail.

based on some suggestions at 
[Failed media import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10849/failed-media-import)

i checked my uploads folder... which was for some reason marked read-only.  i unset that.  i unset the read only attribute from the entire wp-content folder.  i've also tried giving myself total control over that folder, but i'm not convinced it is 'sticking'... as every time i look at the properties it is back to read-only.

i have tried putting this in my htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 7M
php_value upload_max_filesize 7M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value output_buffering on
php_value Timeout 300
php_value KeepAlive On
php_value MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
php_value KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

i've tried upping the memory in wp_config.php.  i have used WXRsplit to split large XML files into smaller <2mb chunks.  so i'm sort of at a loss here at what else to do.  i can't even work until i get this sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today and the client just gave me his login credentials...
The WordPress Import plugin is a...well..

If you don't have a ftp account to grab the data, you can use a plugin like ["WordPress Backup to Dropbox"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-backup-to-dropbox/) to get the data ( there are other plugins which export to other services as well ) and a plugin like ["WP Migrate DB"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to get a database dump, WP Migrate DB will also handle URL and path replacement for you, a great little helper, works well.

So instead of loosing time with so-called importer plugins, just mirror the complete installation. Might take 5 minutes longer, but it works.

Hope this is helpful, even if it doesn't answer your question directly.

Comment: looks like it could be an hour to FTP download the files, but still it can't be much worse than the day i've had.  already have the db backed up w/ wp db manager so going to try that asap.

Comment: yup.  facepalm.  so much easier.